# In @Transaction , thread can work well?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

In method declared with @Transaction , I start a thread which calls other's method in service that also declared with @Transaction.

```
@Transactional
        protected void processJob(final MobileTokenDeliverJob job) {
            if (job.getState() == MobileTokenDeliverJob.STATE_PROCESSING) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("任务正在执行，请在任务出错或停止后再试.");
            }
            Thread workThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //call others' method
                }
            };
            workThread.start();
        }
```

Then I get the exception

```
 "org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException"
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work? The thread runs asynchronously.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The method need long time to run , and thread cannot work . How should I do ?

Comment: Exactly - and it will hold the original transaction open for the entire time - preventing it from committing. So any changes you made _before_ you started the `Thread` would not be seen (depending on isolation). You most likely need `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)` (syntax depending on whose `@Transactional` you are using. If spring, consider an `@Async` method. But the bigger question you need to ask is do you need to transaction for the entire `run()` method?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks , I'll have a try .